# React UseEffects shows warning "Method expression is not of Function type "

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```
const { admin: { fetch: fetchAdmin } } = useDispatch();
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [count, setCount] = useState(15);
const [tick, setTick] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {

        function handleGetData() {
            fetchAdmin({ page: page + 1, count }); // the warning is here
        }

        handleGetData();
    }, [page, count, tick]);


return (
  <div />
)
```

PhpStorm shows warning `Method expression is not of Function type`. 
I've tried move the `handleGetData` function outside `useEffect` still show the same error.
The code is running properly but show those warning in editor.

How to fix this?

Thanks.

======

Seems like its an editor issues

Comment: check in any other editor

Comment: @JatinParmar vscode showing same error

Comment: can you provide full code so I can check the same from my side

Comment: that's all the code. I'm still testing testing the fetched data using inspect element.

Comment: the only solution i found right now change the `useDispatch()` and call the `admin.fetch();` manually, instead of using destructuring object.

Comment: pasted your code in vscode ,i am not facing the same

Comment: @JatinParmar hmm odd. okay will try to reinstall my vscode.

Comment: @JatinParmar reinstall vscode seems fixed the error. no longer showing any errors. thanks!